# Simulating a gaussian pulse for the wave equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, wave-equation

In the process of investigating diffraction of waves, I am starting with a simple problem consisting in injecting a gaussian pulse at the boundary x=0 of a square domain and then solving the wave equation. An absorbing boundary condition is set at x=xmax and to prepare the diffraction by a slit, I extend the problem to 2D by adding a periodic boundary condition on the y component. My code is the following:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
xmax = 4; ymax = 4; tmax = 4; \[Sigma] = 0.5; A = 5;

u1[t_] := A/(\[Sigma] (2*\[Pi])^0.5)*Exp[-t^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)];
(* Gaussian pulse injected at x=0*)
Inj0 = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == u1[t], x == 0 ];
(* Absorbing boundary conditions at xmax*)
bc1 = NeumannValue[-Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y], x == xmax];
(* Periodic boundary conditions for y*)
bc2 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], y == 0, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, ymax}]];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], {t, 2}] == 
     D[u[t, x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[t, x, y], {y, 2}] + bc1, 
    u[0, x, y] == 0, Inj0, bc2, Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0},
    u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];
plots = Table[
   Plot3D[ufun[t, x, y], {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}, 
    PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "SolidGrid"}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {t, 0, 
    tmax - 1, .1}];
ListAnimate[plots]
```

The problem I am facing is that the injected pulse is supposed to be a gaussian, but the simulations I ran show something asymmetric, with ripples in front of the pulse (probably numerical noise but this is not satisfying). Can anyone know what I am doing wrong to get such result ? Thanks very much for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be an inconsidence concerning boundary conditions and initial values.
If you change `Inj0` to start with zero

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
u1[t_] := A/(\[Sigma] (2*\[Pi])^0.5)*Exp[-t^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)];
(*Gaussian pulse injected at x=0*)
Inj0 = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == u1[t - 3 \[Sigma]] - u1[0 - 3 \[Sigma]],x == 0];
```

the simulation runs:

```
    xmax = 4; ymax = 4; tmax = 4; \[Sigma] = 0.5 ; A = 5;
 
(*Absorbing boundary conditions at xmax*)
bc1 = NeumannValue[-Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y], x == xmax];
(*Periodic boundary conditions for y*)
bc2 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], y == 0, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, ymax}]];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], {t, 2}] == 
     D[u[t, x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[t, x, y], {y, 2}] + bc1, 
    u[0, x, y] == 0, Inj0, bc2, Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0},
    u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];
```

Solution, examplary for `y==0`:

```
Plot3D[ufun[t, x, 0], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, tmax},MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ulrich, it is indeed working fine now ! The corrections you made are perfect. A last question yet: I do not understand the reason why $3\sigma$ must be substracted in the function's argument. Could you enlighten me on this please ?

Comment: @Seb For `t==0` you get `u1[t - 3 \[Sigma]] - u1[0 - 3 \[Sigma]]==u1[0- 3 \[Sigma]] - u1[0 - 3 \[Sigma]] ==0`  consitent starting values !

Comment: Crystal clear, thanks again !

Comment: @Seb - saying thanks is meaningless if you don't at least **upvote**; or in this case, **upvote and accept** the answer.

Comment: @Bob: Thanks (no pun intended) for your remark, I did not know (newbee's mistake).